# PIN number verify in text field

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp, ojdbc

I am writing a code to enter a number (pin code) in textfield and search weather the number is present in database or not and if present redirt to some other page else display incorrect password. Please help as I am a newbie and am stuck .
i am using jsp to connect to oracle database and html as UI.

```
Class.forName("Oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");      
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","scott","wipro123");
String q = "Select * from Login where pin="pin_textbox"";
rs=st.executeQuery(q);
System.out.println("catty");
while(rs.next())
    {
            // dont know what to write after this... Please help me.

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/CountRecordsUsingPreparedStatement.htm)

```
int numberOfRows = null;
String q = "Select count(*) from Login where pin=?";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(q);
pst.setString(1, pin_textbox);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    numberOfRows = rs.getInt(1);
} else {
    System.out.println("error: could not get the record counts");
}
```

By using `numberOfRows >= 1` condition you can redirect or display error page

Comment: Actually, this is not injection safe, so it's a security vulnerability. Use prepared statements.

Comment: Far better with prepared statement :) +1